# What is the nilradical of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$?

Tags: lie-algebras

I'm really embarrassed to ask but what is the nilradical of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$, i.e. the set of ad-nilpotent elements of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C}) = \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$$? This must be standard knowledge but I couldn't find a reference.

Clearly, all nilpotent matrices and all diagonal matrices are in the nilradical. What else?

Comment: it is zero. This is really a consequence of definitions, and these questions are better suited to math stackexchange

Comment: @Venkataramana Um, actually it's the scalar matrices.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong definition of nilradical:  it's the largest nilpotent *ideal* in the Lie algebra.  For $\mathfrak{gl}_n$, the only proper ideals are  the trace-free matrices $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ and the scalar matrices $\mathbb{C}\cdot I$.  The former is not nilpotent (it's simple), and the latter is.  So the scalar matrices are the nilradical.

Answer (score 3):

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is *reductive*, i.e., we have
$\mathfrak{g}=[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]\oplus Z(\mathfrak{g})$, where $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$ is semisimple (in fact it is $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ in this case), and the center is abelian and equals the solvable radical and the nilradical. So the nilradical here equals 
$$\operatorname{nil}(\mathfrak{g})=Z(\mathfrak{g})=\mathbb{C}\cdot \operatorname{id}.$$